# Creating two dimensional arrays from a given Object Vector

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I am still trying to understand Java programming and have met with this challenge, I have a table and would like to load data into it via this DefaultTableModel

```
private Vector <Object> Headings =new Vector <Object>();
private Vector <Object> Data = new Vector <Object> ();
    Headings = acquire.Account("StudentHeader");
    Data = acquire.Account("StudentData");
    Object[] ids = Headings.toArray();
    //Object[][] out = to2DimArray(Data);  


  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(out, ids);
```

As required, "out" is a two dimensional array. The problem is that I don't know how to transfer/change my "Data" to the two dimensional array that is needed by the Table. I tried using the Vector form of the DefaultTableModel but there was an error, so I decided to use the array form which does load the headings.
Can you please show me how to convert a vector into a 2-D array so I can load my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Data object is a monodimensional Vector, so you can't convert it directly to a bidimensional object.
Try to build Data as `Vector<Vector<Object>>` where each element is a row of your table.

Something like this:

```
Vector <Object> headings = new Vector <Object>();       
Vector <Vector<Object>> data = new Vector <Vector<Object>> ();

headings = acquire.Account("StudentHeader");   

for(int i = 0 ; i < yourStudentDataNumber ; i++) {
    Vector <Object> dataElement = new Vector <Object>();
    dataElement = acquire.Account("StudentHeader"); 
    //i don't know what is acquire object, this for loop is only an example
    // however you need to build a Vector<Object> for each row of the table

    data.add(dataElement);
}       

Object[] ids = headings.toArray();

int numberOfRow = data.size();     

Object[][] bidimArray = new Object[numberOfRow][];      

for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfRow ; i++) {
    bidimArray[i] = data.get(i).toArray();
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(bidimArray, ids);
```

Comment: i tried a similar method and it did worked, something like what I am going to paste now if it is going to work. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Logically speacking, A vector is a resizable one dimensional array, so I don't think you can convert it to a two dimensional array.

Instead of using the [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), I think you'll can extend the [TableModel class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) or create an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) of the [AbstractTableModel class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), then create your own table Model which you can then use to instantiate your Table.

check [TableDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDemoProject/src/components/TableDemo.java)

.....

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                    "Last Name",
                                    "Sport",
                                    "# of Years",
                                    "Vegetarian"};
    private Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    /*
     * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
     * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
     * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
     * rather than a check box.
     */
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }
```

......

it explains this implementation pretty well .

Comment: The problem is that I would like to add columns and rows to the table. I have no idea how this can be done using abstractTableModel, but I do know how to do so with DefaultTableModel. Is there a way to add columns and rows with Abstracttablemodel that you can assist me with because, seriously working with Abstract is quite easier.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is what I did to get out of this, and it worked:

```
Vector <Object> Headings =new Vector <Object>();
Vector <Object> Data = new Vector <Object> ();
Vector <Object> Extract = new Vector <Object> ();
Headings = acquire.Account("IncomeHeader");
Data = acquire.Account("IncomeData");

int DataSize = Data.size(); int colum = Headings.size();
    int round = DataSize/colum; int cover = DataSize; int t =1;
    while(t<=round){
        Extract = getVector(Data, colum);
    model.addRow(Extract); 
    t++;
    }

private Vector<Object> getVector(Vector<Object> data, int colum) {
      Vector vector = new Vector(); int h = data.size(); int r = 0;
    while(h>s){
        r++; 
        vector.add(data.get(s));
        s++;
    if(r==colum){
        System.out.println("vector: "+vector);
        return vector;
    }
    }
    return null;
}
```